# Travel Budget for Faculty Members in USA

Tags: conference, funding, travel

How much budget do faculty members in US  have to travel to conferences every year?

I am looking for the average travel support in CS or Engineetring  departments (not out of my own contracts) across US top 100 schools, for tenured professors with accepted papers at conferences. Consider places like University of Washington.

The background of the this question is, I like to find out, once my tenure track funding package is finished, would there be a minimum research support from the department, or I am on my own. It makes sense that if my paper is accepted, the university pays for it (I present my work under the university banner). Before asking my department, I like to equip myself with prior information.

Comment: This is going to be way too broad / too specific... it will vary by institution, college at the institution, and potentially even department.

Comment: Made specific for clarity.

Comment: Why do people downvote? how else are you going to ask a question in academia?

Comment: You have not stated the discipline you are interested in. It might be different for CS where conferences are the main publishing venue than Math for example.

Comment: Made more precise.

Comment: If you are considering a job offer, you should ask the department chair.  The department chair will want to help you negotiate with administration since that brings money into the department.

Answer (score 8):

Although I am a mathematician and not a CS or engineering professor, I would overwhelmingly expect that at a place like the University of Washington tenure track faculty members would be expected to secure external grant funding (for example from the NSF) and use this to cover their travel expenses.

Universities often provide startup funds which you can use for this purpose during the first couple of years -- but these don't get renewed when you run out.

In the long run, if you don't succeed in obtaining external funding, it is unlikely that your department would rush in to fill the gap. My department (less prestigious than Washington) provides a little bit of money to faculty members without grant support, but it is only enough to attend to one or maybe two conferences a year.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, the question is too broad to be answered in a useful way.  There might be a discretionary budget or a development budget which could be used for travel, but it could also be used for other things.  There might be a travel fund, but it might not be guaranteed to any particular faculty member.  But I will try to give a useful answer:  Most faculty are employed in teaching positions where funding is limited and research is not a priority.  In these cases travel budget is often zero.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I modified the question. So I guess there is typically little or no support. And if I don't get grants, no travel.